# email disappear after sent in acivities under contact

Tags: email

[image]

I have sent an email with the email tab understand contact, it appeared in the activities for a while without dates. but after i refresh the page, it disappears . as if it is completely disappeared. any idea why this is happening?
I am on a trailhead playground org.

Comment: Can you check if you have any restricted domain under Einstein Activity Capture--> settings? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323391&type=1)

Comment: That's actually a good idea. In Einstein, but default the emails with users in the same company are excluded. For testing purpose The contact I am using has an email address that is in the same email domain as my own email. That's why the emails are excluded. I changed the email address of the contact to another email with a different domain, now it works.  Salesforce actually uses the email domain to determine whether this email is between colleagues or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Vinay's question. And ask a simple test i got the answer. In Einstein, but default the emails with users in the same company are excluded. For testing purpose The contact I am using has an email address that is in the same email domain as my own email. That's why the emails are excluded. I changed the email address of the contact to another email with a different domain, now it works. Salesforce actually uses the email domain to determine whether this email is between colleagues or not. –